# descent override Safari

Tags: css, fonts, safari

I'm using font that have many space under the text,
[which could be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2x6O.png).

I found out that descent-override could be a solution and it actually helped, however when I've started to check how it looks on different browsers I've noticed that it does not work on Safari. Is there any replacement that I can use?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: xyz;
    src: url("./fonts/CallieshaDemoRegular.ttf");
    descent-override: 90%;
}
```

Comment: Its currently not supported on Safari at all (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/descent-override#browser_compatibility) and I don't think you have an easy way of mimicking this font-specific thing. I don't think there is a solution until Safari also inplements.

Comment: thanks! it looks like I'm going to opt for a different font